# Is there a way to count how many times a specific word appears in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am new to R and web scraping. For practice purposes I am trying to scrape information from a fake book website. So far I have managed to scrape the book titles, find the mean length of each word in the book titles, find the most used word and also find the most used word excluding stopwords. However, I am now trying to find how many times a specific word occurs. For example, how many times the word 'me' appears in the book titles, yet I am not sure how to isolate a specific word.

Code so far:

```
url<-'http://books.toscrape.com/index.html'

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('h3 a') %>%
  html_attr('title')->titles
titles

values<-lapply(titles,nchar)
mean(unlist(values))

mostUsedWord<-head(sort(table(tolower(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+')))), decreasing = TRUE))[1]
mostUsedWord 

all_words <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+')))
noStopWords <- head(sort(table(all_words[!all_words %in% tm::stopwords()]), decreasing = TRUE))[1:3]
noStopWords
```

I would like to find out how many times specific words occur, not just the most frequent words that are used.

Comment: Hi, could you include the details of which libraries you have used? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
word='me'
data.frame(word = table(all_words)) %>% dplyr::filter(word.all_words == word)
```

```
word.all_words word.Freq
1             me         1
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for. However, when I implement this I am getting this error: Error: unexpected symbol in "word.all_words word.Freq"

Comment: Ah that's part of the output - I've separated it now to make it more clear